# justifyContent not working in my card react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, jsx

I want my content in center ..equal margin from top and bottom so i am using  justifyContent='center' but nothing happening

```
              <View style={styles.allAttendeesContainer}>
              <Image
              style={styles.imageSpeaker}
              source={{
                uri: item.image
              }}/>
              <View>
              <Text style={[styles.textSpeakerDetail,{fontWeight:'bold',color:'#000'}]}>Muthu Ramalingam</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textSpeakerDetail}>HelloLead,DexPatent</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textSpeakerDetail}>Information Technology and Services</Text>
              </View>
              </View>
```

This is my jsx
and below is my styling

```
 allAttendeesContainer:{
 height:125,
 flexDirection:'row',
 borderBottomWidth:0.5,
 flex:1,
 justifyContent:'center'
 },
 textSpeakerDetail:{
  fontSize:18,
  },
  imageSpeaker:{ 
  width: 75,
  marginHorizontal:'3%',
  height: 75, 
  borderRadius: 50,
  },
  inviteBox:{
  marginLeft:'10%',
  height:30,
  width:80,
  borderColor:'green',
  borderRadius:50,
  borderWidth:1,
  justifyContent:'center'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used

> alignItems: 'center'

like this

```
allAttendeesContainer: {
height: 125,
flexDirection: 'row',
borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
},
```